# Quickblox iOS location sample error

Tags: ios, objective-c, location, sample, quickblox

I'm trying to start a new project with QuickBlox framework.

I created an account and an application on the admin panel and got my precious keys. Then I downloaded the iOS-location-sample code and just replaced in **AppDelegate.m** these lines with my values :

```
[QBApplication sharedApplication].applicationId = MY_APP_ID;
[QBConnection registerServiceKey:MY_KEY];
[QBConnection registerServiceSecret:MY_SECRET];
[QBSettings setAccountKey:MY_ACCOUNT_ID];
```

By the way I also needed to add in **SLLMapViewController.m** these lines in order to make the localization works on iOS 8+ :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];   // Added
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];      // Added
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

and in **SimpleSample-location_users-ios-Prefix.pch**

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow localization for this app ?</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow localization when in background ?</string>
```

My problem is when I launch the sample app without changing account/application keys, it works. But after replacing them with my own values, the splash screen keeps loading and I get this in console (after some other lines) :

```
2015-04-14 16:37:24.429 Location[2057:992725] Request headers: {
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    "QB-SDK" = "iOS 2.2.3";
    "QB-Token" = 1db6140b1a921ad88ee24f900b814535a81d5aaa;
    "QuickBlox-REST-API-Version" = "0.1.1";
}
2015-04-14 16:37:24.692 Location[2057:992708] Error = 
   Error reasons:(null)
2015-04-14 16:37:24.691 Location[2057:992725] Response headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Tue, 14 Apr 2015 14:37:24 GMT";
    "QB-Token-ExpirationDate" = "2015-04-14 16:37:24 UTC";
    "QuickBlox-REST-API-Version" = "0.1.1";
    Server = "nginx/1.0.15";
    Status = "404 Not Found";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-Rack-Cache" = miss;
    "X-Request-Id" = 13dd7171da034601955925a38f076c21;
    "X-Runtime" = "0.012323";
    "X-UA-Compatible" = "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
}
```

Does anybody have a clue on what's going on ? I've noticed *Status = "404 Not Found"* but don't know what to do about it...

Comment: Please give me your test credentials so I can debug a problem.

Comment: `[QBApplication sharedApplication].applicationId = 22130;`
    `[QBConnection registerServiceKey:@"gzNpBxZvDVKwrw3"];`
    `[QBConnection registerServiceSecret:@"LOaKvRJBtRkLptz"];`
    `[QBSettings setAccountKey:@"7YGnTY6FnvBhxr8PjLq3"];`

Comment: Take a look at the log. http://pastebin.com/yc7mmC6R 
You are calling QBRequest geoDataWithFilter, which calls api.quickblox.com/geodata/find.json, and if there is no search results, you have the 404 not found error. You need at least 1 pin

Comment: I tried, in AppDelegate just after setting up my credentials, to create a user, sign up, login and then create a pin. I get 401 Unauthorized then 404 Not Found. I tried to login with my user login/password and skip the creation part, still nothing... Everything I used is here http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-ios#Add_User_Base_to_your_application and here http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-location_users-ios#Check-in

Comment: Can you post the Xcode log of request, not only response